# Django custom decorator redirect problem

Tags: django, redirect, decorator

I try to write a custom decorator in Django.
I want to redirect users to custom login page if they are not logged in via that page.
I have written the decorator and I debugged it. Although it works well if user is not logged in, after user logged in it gives error as

```
The view APPNAME.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

You can find my code below. Why my decorator simply jump to `return wraps(func)(inner_decorator)` section after authentication in private alfa page ?

Thanks

```
def private_alfa_required():    
def decorator(func):
    def inner_decorator(request,*args, **kwargs):
        if 'isPrivateAlfaUser' not in request.session or request.session['isPrivateAlfaUser'] != True:
            return render_to_response('homepage.html') 

    return wraps(func)(inner_decorator)

return decorator

@private_alfa_required()
def home(request):
 .....



def home2(request):
  .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you haven't actually called the view function if your test succeeds.

```
if 'isPrivateAlfaUser' not in request.session or request.session['isPrivateAlfaUser'] != True:
    return render_to_response('homepage.html') 
else:
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

As a secondary note, you don't need the outer level of wrapper here because your decorator doesn't take any arguments. If you drop that, you also need to drop the `()` on the decorator itself.

Comment: I have written in that way but now it gives error as 'Tried home in module APPNAME.main.views. Error was: 'APPNAME.main.views.home' is not a callable.' Actually I didn't understand the logic  behind the decorators. Where can I find a good documentation ?

Comment: There's an error somewhere, probablyl in your `views.py`. Post the entire content of the `home` function so we can see what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a context to render to response

```
return render_to_response('homepage.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or render to response won't work