# Django custom decorator for redirections

Tags: python, django, django-views, decorator, python-decorators

I'm deploying a multi-domain platform in Django, with some model logic for performing redirections between websites.

As the redirection mapping is going to get slightly bulky I'd rather decorate each view as opposed to replicate the code for redirections in every view (I'm sticking to function-based views for this project). As the logic could possibly be changed too, I need to have it all in one place and I'd really like to use a custom decorator for that.

I've been trying different syntaxes in order to define a decorator and I'm getting all sorts of problems. https://pythonbasics.org/decorators/ I'm using the syntax I see here but I couldn't apply it to Django views at first. I'm using Django 3.2. This is the thread that most resambles my situation and which helped me get closer to the result I want [Django custom decorator redirect problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874908/django-custom-decorator-redirect-problem) however my decorator view still returns None instead of an HttpResponse object and I don't understand.

**Decorator 1**

```
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("DEBUGGING")
        if settings.DEBUG == False or request.user.is_superuser == False:
            return render(request, 'myapp/manutenzione.html')
        func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

**Decorator 2** for my redirection

```
def reindirizzamenti_necessari(func):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("REINDIRIZZAMENTI")


        sito = get_current_site(request)
        dominio = sito.domain
        if dominio[0:4] == "www.":
            dominio = dominio.split("www.")[1]
        try:

            dominio = Dominio.objects.get(dominio = dominio)
            sito_generale = False

            # Redirect to the main domain
            if not dominio.principale:
                redirect_necessario = True
                url = '/redirect/' + dominio.città.nome.lower()
                return redirect(url)
            context['luogo'] = dominio.città

        except:

            print("DOMINIO GENERALE")

            if dominio.endswith(".it"):
                return redirect("https://www.mymaindomainname.com") #not using this now, just moving forward to func()

            func(request, *args, **kwargs) # <---- I THINK THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING (from checking the prints, I get this last one)
    return inner
```

**My decorated view**

```
@debugging
@reindirizzamenti_necessari
def homepage(request):

    context = {}

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

**My current redirection view**

```
def redirect_domain(request, city):

    città_url = City.objects.get(nome = city)
    dominio_principale_città = Dominio.objects.get(città = città_url, principale = True)
    url_finale = "https://" + dominio_principale_città.dominio

    return redirect(url_finale)
```

When I call the "homepage" view now I'm getting

```
ValueError at /my-path

The view myapp.views.inner didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: You need to return a response from the `inner` functions in your decorators, return what the view returns in the basic case, otherwise you are just calling the view and not doing anything with the response: `return func(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thank you, it seems this was the really last bit that I was missing!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should use Middleware instead of the decorator.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-view

Comment: I considered that option but I will need to apply the redirections on a per-view basis so I thought the decorator approach would be spot-on indeed